# Unusual chord progression: I7-VIImaj7 (#VIImaj7 ?)

Tags: harmony, functional-harmony

So I came up with this little tune that roughly follows the standard 12-bar blues form but it substitutes the subdominant (IV7 chord) with VIImaj7. It sounds unusual but quite smooth and not jarring at all. How do I explain it in terms of functional harmony? Why it sounds good? Second question: do you know any examples of similar progression in music? The closest I could find is G7->Gbmaj7 in Jobim's Desafinado but there the context is different (the key of F and the sequence has more of a passing/shortlived character)?

Here the whole progression for clarity:

```
|F7///|////|////|////|
|Emaj7///|////|F7///|////|
|Bbm7///|C9sus///|F7////|////|
```

Comment: You should probably write out the whole progression, because there is some confusion about whether `F` is your tonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the sevenths for simplicity, if you go from `I` to `VII` - meaning the tonic major chord to a major chord rooted on the leading tone - and you want to see functional harmony, an example that comes to mind is *Red Roses for a Blue Lady*. In that song the chords are `C B7 E7 A7 Dm7 G7...`, which is clear a series of secondary dominants.

Obviously the secondary dominant chords are different that your `VIImaj7` major seventh chord, but the difference is in the quality of the sevenths, not the roots. The initial root progression `I VII` and the triad portions of the chords at least suggest, to me, the sound of the opening to *Red Roses for a Blue Lady*. It adds a sort of sophisticated sound to a basic blues progression, depending how you play it, I'm thinking more jazz than something like barrelhouse blues.

In regard to *functional harmony* you should consider *what chord comes after* the `VIImaj7`, what comes next has much more importance for function that what chord came before. If you just go back to the tonic, like `I VIImaj7 I`, you don't have much for functional harmony, and the movement is more of an auxiliary movement, a neighbor chord.

> ...or should I say #VIImaj7 if we are assuming blues so possibly mixolydian modality

Just a technical note, Roman numerals are relative to either a major scale or a major/minor key, depending on which convention you follow. Roman numerals for chords rooted on the seventh scale degree are particularly confusing and inconsistent compared to other chords. But in jazz I think I've only seen Roman numerals in relation to major scale degrees. So, the common ones are `viio` for the diminished leading tone chord, and `♭VII` for the minor subtonic chord, or as you pointed out, it could be the mixolydian subtonic chord. `VII` is less common, but should read as "major triad root on the leading tone." `♯VII` is confusing, because it looks like "major triad" rooted on a leading tone raised a half step, which would be enharmonically equal to the tonic. I think you should label `F7 Emaj7` as `I7 VIImaj7`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful clarification on the roman numerals. Indeed the VIImaj7 seems a correct way though arguably a bit misleading.

Comment: I guess this question could be narrowed down to whether I just interpret it as auxiliary movement or some sort of a secondary substitute to the tritone substitute (so Emaj7 substituting E7 which is tritone sub for Bb7 which should be there in the blues form). I always associated the auxilitary movement with something more temporary or not structurally significant and here we have some sort of replacement for a subdominant function

Comment: I'm not a fan of invoking tritone substitution when not involving a dominant or even a tritone in the substitute chord. I understand your feeling about auxiliary and temporary, but I would point out that non-functional shouldn't be misconstrued as 'unimportant.' If we set aside terms "function" and "subdominant", and think about "purpose", your `VIImaj7` chord provides non-dominant harmonic contrast to the tonic chord, and that is an important structural purpose of bars 5-6 of a 12 bar blues. You just fulfill that purpose with a chromatic chord.